# how do i print array dynamically from 1 to 100 angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

app.js

```
(function (){
  var app = angular.module('starter');

  app.controller('NumberController',function($scope){

      $scope.items = 
                    [
                      1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10

                    ]
/* i want my program to print numbers form 1 to 100 dynamically  */

  });

})();
```

Comment: and where do you intend to print?? console or html

Comment: in html as items in a list  <ion-list class="list1">
          <ion-item ng-repeat="item in items"> {{item}} </ion-item>
        </ion-list>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ng-repeat to achieve this

Angularjs code

```
var app = angular.module('starter');

  app.controller('NumberController',function($scope){

      $scope.items = [];
      var len=100;
      for(var i=1;i<101;i++)
        $scope.items.push(i);
  });
```

HTML

```
<div ng-app='starter' ng-controller='NumberController' >
  <div ng-repeat='item in items'>
   {{item}}
   </div>
</div>
```